# TypeError: Cannot read property 'home_address' of undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch, use-effect

I know `line#24` runs before `useEffect()`. How to resolve this!! It is showing error that can not read property of `undefined`. You can also check data coming from `API` in `POSTMAN`.

```
1.  function App() {
2.  const[apiData,setApiData]=useState([]);
3.  const id=13
5.    useEffect(() => {
6.      async function loadData(url) {
7.        let response = await fetch(url, {
8.          method: 'POST',
9.          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
10.         // body: JSON.stringify({id:13})
11.       })
12.       let data = await response.json();
13.       console.log(data)
15.       setApiData(data);
17.     }
18.     loadData(`http://eign-backend.herokuapp.com/property/get-property/${id}/`);
19.   }
20.     , [])
21.   
22.   return (
23.     <div className="App">
24.     <h1>{apiData[0].home_address}</h1>
25.       </div>
27.   );
28. }
29. export default App;
```

Comment: Did you try to log `console.log(apiData)` to check how it is defined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check it before using:

```
<h1>{apiData[0] ? apiData[0].home_address : ""}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's works now. Can you explain why i have to check .Do i have to check for every jsx tag that i want to render

Comment: You're welcome. You have to check the variable and be sure that the variable has the value and if it had you can do what you wanted to do.